# How to you define attaching a texture array to a FBO's color attachment point visually?

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, framebuffer

I read that in layered rendering, we create a 2D texture array (GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY):

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, TextureColorbufferName);
glTexParameteri(....
glTexImage3D(...
```

and can attach it to FBO:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, TextureColorbufferName, 0);
```

What i find hard to understand visually is how can a layer of textures be bound to a single color attachment point in FBO? Isnt color attachment 0 (or any of GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi ) a single "image" in themselves?

In more detail:

Before reading about texture arrays, this was my understanding of FBOS

```
                      +--------------+
         +-----------+| FBO object   ++--------------------------------------------+
         |            |              +---------------------+                       |
         |            +--------------+                     |                       |
         |                     +                           |                       |
         |                     |                           |                       |
         |                     |                           |                       |
         v                     v                           v                       v
 +-----------------+     +-----------------+      +-----------------+       +------------------+
 |color attachment |     |color attachment |      |depth attachment |       |stencil attachment|
 |    0            |     |   1             |      |                 |       |                  |
 +-----------------+     +-----------------+      +-----------------+       +------------------+
                                                                               (this too)
  (this is actually        (this is also a                (this too)
   one texture or          texture of renderbuffer)
    one renderbuffer)
```

But after reading about texture arrays, is this how it really is?

```
                          +--------------+
             +-----------+| FBO object   ++--------------------------------------------+
             |            |              +---------------------+                       |
             |            +--------------+                     |                       |
             |                     +                           |                       |
             |                     |                           |                       |
             |                     |                           |                       |
             v                     v                           v                       v
     +-----------------+     +-----------------+      +-----------------+       +------------------+
     |color attachment |     |color attachment |      |depth attachment |       |stencil attachment|
     |    0            |     |   1             |      |                 |       |                  |
     +-----+--+------+-+     +-----------------+      +-----------------+       +------------------+
           |  |      |
           |  |      v+
           |  v+      +----------------------------------+
           |   +--------->+                              v
           v              |                              +
  +----------------+  +---v-------------+                |
  |                |  |                 |            +---v------------+
  |texture array[0]|  |texture array[1] |            |texture array[n]|
  |                |  |                 |            |                |
  |                |  |                 |            |                |
  |                |  |                 |            |                |
  +----------------+  +-----------------+            +----------------+
```

i.e is each attachment itself a collection of various textures?

This is hard for me to visualize how 1 color attachment point maps to multiple textures.

What happens if i blit from 1 FBO (one that is bound to texture_2d_array) to another(one that is bound to texture_2d)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. It works because OpenGL defines that it *does work*. What goes into a framebuffer binding point is exactly what OpenGL *says* goes in one.

Comment: I edited my questioon with more detail. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A texture is a *collection* of images. You do not attach a texture to an FBO attachment point; you attach an image *within* the texture to an FBO attachment point.

So at no point do you attach multiple *textures* to a single attachment point.

[Array textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) are just textures that store an array of images within a mipmap level. A non array 2D texture only stores one image per mipmap level. A cubemap stores 6 images per mipmap. An array texture stores a user-provided number of images per mipmap.

However, you can attach a [layered image](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Semantics) to an attachment point. A mipmap level of an [array texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) is a layered image, as are several other things.

An FBO that is built from layered images can be used for [layered rendering](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering_2) via a Geometry Shader. This allows the GS to pipe a particular primitive output to a specific layer index within the layered FBO.

How you visualize this is up to you.

Comment: @Nicol.As you pointed out [this link](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Layered_Images) is also a very good explanation. Thank you.

Comment: After a lot of reading and trial-and-error, I finally solved this with `glFramebufferTextureLayer`. I was originally trying to bind the array texture with `glFramebufferTexture3D`. Leaving this here in case it helps someone.